# Open WinForm from SignalR Client

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

i have used this sample [GitHub SignalR Samples]
https://github.com/nthdeveloper/SignalRSamples
it use a winforms as a signalR server
it use two clients winforms and a javascript
it append the client message in the textbox

```
   private void SimpleHub_MessageReceived(string senderClientId, string message)
    {
        //One of the clients sent a message, log it
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            string clientName = _clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == senderClientId)?.Name;

            writeToLog($"{clientName}:{message}");
        }));
    }
```

i need to open a form based on message

```
  private void SimpleHub_MessageReceived(string senderClientId, string message)
    {
        //One of the clients sent a message, log it
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            string clientName = _clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == senderClientId)?.Name;
            switch (message)
            {
                case "form1":
                    Form1 frm = new Form1();
                    frm.Show();
                    break;
                case "form2":
                   Form2 frm = new Form();
                    frm.Show();
                    break;

                default:
                    // code block
                    break;
            }
          
          
        }));
    }
```

i have tried that code the form opens and stays loading i can not interact with it
what is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Form.Show` does not block causing it to go out of scope immediately.

You need to use `Form.ShowDialog`. This will block allowing the life cycle of the form to complete before going out of scope.

With that being said, try this:

```cs
switch (message)
{
    case "form1":
        using(var frm = new Form1())
        {
            frm.ShowDialog(this);
        }
        break;
    case "form2":
        using(var frm = new Form2())
        {
            frm.ShowDialog(this);
        }
        break;
    default:
        // code block
        break;
}
```